# Make while loop not print when user enters "quit" (still prints STR after user says quit but program ends)

Tags: c, string, loops, while-loop, scanf

Instructions:

> Prompt the user for one or two tokens, space-delimited, inputs of at most
>   20 characters.
>
> - If the user provides more than 20 characters before a newline is reached, print the provided error message.
> - If the number of tokens is incorrect, print the appropriate error message.
> - If the input is correct, print the appropriate token types.
>
> Prompt the user for input (and provide output) until the user provides a single STR token `quit` (case insensitive). The program should quit immediately without output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool isNumeric(char *str); 
void tokenizer(char *token);

int main() {
    char buff[20];
    while (strcmp(buff, "quit") != 0) {
        printf("> ");
        scanf("%[^\n]s", buff);
        if (sizeof(buff) - 1 < strlen(buff)) {
            printf("Input string too long.\n");        
            exit(1);
        }
        char *token;
        tokenizer(token = strtok(buff, " "));
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

bool isNumeric(char *str) {
    while (*str != '\0') {
        if (*str < '0' || *str > '9')
            return false;
        str++;
    }
    return true;
}

void tokenizer(char *token) {
    int tokenCount = 0;
    while (token != NULL) {
        tokenCount++;
        if (tokenCount > 2) {
            printf("\rERROR! Incorrect number of tokens found.\n");          
            exit(1);
        }
        if (isNumeric(token)) {
            printf("INT ");
        } else {
            printf("STR ");
        }
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
}
```

OUTPUT: an Endless program that says STR. I need help with the loop condition.

Comment: Step 1 `scanf("%[^\n]s", buff);` --> `fgets(buff, sizeof buff, stdin);`  Step 2: `strtok(NULL, " ");` --> `strtok(NULL, " \n");`

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
int main() {
    char buff[20];
    while (strcmp(buff, "quit") != 0) {
       ...
    }
}
```

your code invokes *Undefined Behavior*, since `buff` is not initialized! Either use `scanf()` or `fgets(buff, sizeof buff, stdin);` before the loop to read the input once, or use a do-while loop instead of a while loop.

Moreover, this `strtok(NULL, " ");` should be `strtok(NULL, " \n");` to also use the newline character as a delimeter, and not just the whitespace.

Your infinite loop comes from this:

```
scanf("%[^\n]s", buff);
```

which should be:

```
scanf("%s", buff);
```

and you will be fine, since you don't want to mesh with the newline there.

Putting everything together, you get:

```
do {
    printf("> ");
    scanf("%s", buff);
    if (sizeof(buff) - 1 < strlen(buff)) {
        printf("Input string too long.\n");        
        exit(1);
    }
    char *token = strtok(buff, " ");
    tokenizer(token);
} while (strcmp(buff, "quit") != 0);
```

Comment: thanks it worked the program ends when I input "quit" but the output is still STR. I need the program not to output anything.

Comment: You are welcome, updated my answer @yoobi, please *accept it*, since it answers your question.

Comment: ok but  if (sizeof(buff) - 1 < strlen(buff)) {
                 printf("Input string too long.\n");        
                 exit(1);                   }  this statement makes me run out of the loop, how can I make it so the loop keeps running?

Comment: What is your question @yoobi?